# How does assigning more variables affect performance of an app?

Tags: android, kotlin, variables

I would say `println(sum)` is more readable than `println(var1.roundToInt() + var2.roundToInt())`, which is very important in my opinion, but requires assigning a new variable. How does this affect app performance and memory usage? Is it technically more efficient to use `println(var1.roundToInt() + var2.roundToInt())`, whether this is the same? Maybe some optimizations happen when compiling an app? I'm mainly asking about Android app, but also interested in how it works in other platforms, systems, or programming languages. Thanks.

```
import kotlin.math.roundToInt

fun main() {
    val var1 = 1.0 + 3.3
    val var2 = 5.8 - 1.99
    val sum = var1.roundToInt() + var2.roundToInt()
    println(var1.roundToInt() + var2.roundToInt())
    println(sum)
}
```

Comment: Press shift twice and write "byte code", then in the new editor click on "Decompile", you can see the Java version for yourself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case its unlikely you're actually storing more variables-  between the initial compiler and the JIT compilation of the JVM it will probably be optimized away, so it will make no difference.

Ignoring that, lets say it actually did store it in multiple variables.  Writing to a register takes fractions of a nanosecond.  Writing to a log like you do in println will take microseconds.  You're optimizing the part that ultimately doesn't matter.  Don't worry about optimizations on that level unless you really know you need to (hint:  you almost never need to, and if you do you should almost certainly be writing in C and not kotlin/Java).

Comment: There was the argument that you should avoid unnecessarily creating *objects* in Android (this example is just primitives so it doesn't apply)- they had a whole series on performance optimisation that encouraged this approach, so that's possibly why people are worried about it. And depending on what you're doing, sometimes it matters - if you're updating a custom view at 60fps (or 90 or 120 on some devices) allocations can start to creep up pretty quickly. If you want to avoid too many GCs or memory pressure on low-end devices, it's worth considering. Not for one extra object though!

Comment: @cactustictacs IT wouldn't apply anyway-  assigning a variable isn't creating an object.  Creating requires a call to new (in kotlin, a call to a constructor).  There are places you want to avoid that, because memory allocation is slow.  But if that's what he was asking, he needs to ask it better- that's an entirely different question, this is about assigning a variable.

Comment: Yeah that's why I said it doesn't apply here because it's just primitives, but I read the question as "should I avoid creating variables?" - and like you say, generally it doesn't matter, but there *are* some cases where you might care about it, and Android does (did?) push that idea quite heavily in the past. So I just wanted to add that bit of context. But most of the time when people ask it really doesn't matter - check out the number of allocations the Android framework churns out just ticking along normally. One extra *int* (or even an object) out of 30,000 or whatever isn't a worry!

Comment: It's not just about primitives.  If it was an object but you weren't creating a new one, just assigning to variables it also wouldn't invoke memory allocation and thus would be lightning fast. Assigning a reference requires no time at all. val x=getFoo() where Foo is an object takes less than a nanosecond, if Foo isn't being created. Creating an object takes time, especially if it causes other subobjects to be created.  But this question was about assignment, not creation.

Comment: Oh sorry I see what you mean, yeah - maybe they *were* just asking about intermediate variables for expressions they're already running. I just wanted to mention the allocations side since it's more important and relevant, and the worry sounded familiar as far as official Android best practice goes. Just in case it was part of why they were asking